# How to override the keys in windows services .exe.config file through VSTS release definition

Tags: deployment, windows-services, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am working on VSTS release task for deploying the Windows Services Project. Unfortunately, we are not creating any Build Definition for creating drop folder.
But, my client will provide drop folder for this project, what I need is “I want to override the keys of an existing .exe.config file” at release level.

For creating the Windows Services Deploy task,I followed this [Windows Services Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=julioarrudac.build-deploy-extension)

For example my drop folder looks like below:

[image]

Many thanks for this reference [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sonam_rastogi_blogs/2014/08/18/update-configuration-files-using-powershell/) and It's a very useful for changing values in config file using Power Shell commands. I have doubt in from that reference link :
For Example, If had a Code like this :

```
<erecruit.tasks>
<tasks>
  <task name="AA" taskName="AA">
    <parameters>
      <param key="connectionString">Server="XXXX"</param>
    </parameters>
</task>
```

How to change this above connectionstring value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Tokenizer** task in [Release Management Utility tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.utilitytasks) extension.

1. Install Release Management Utility tasks extension
2. Add Tokenizer with XPath/Regular expressions task to release definition (Specify Source filename and Configuration Json filename)

Config file sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="TestKey1" value="__Token1__" />
      <add key="TestKey2" value="__Token2__" />
      <add key="TestKey3" value="__Token3__" />
      <add key="TestKey4" value="__Token4__" />
    </appSettings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Configuration Json file (Default Environment is the environment name in release definitioin):

```
{
   "Default Environment":{
      "CustomVariables":{
         "Token2":"value_from_custom2",
         "Token3":"value_from_custom3"
      },
      "ConfigChanges":[
         {
            "KeyName":"/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='TestKey1']",
            "Attribute":"value",
            "Value":"value_from_xpath"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Then the value of `TestKey1` (key) will be related to `value_from_xpath` and the values of `TestKey2` and `TestKey3` will be related to `value_from_custom2` and `value_from_custom3`.

On the other hand, you can use release variables directly if you don’t specify Configuration Json filename.

For example, there is `__TokenVariable1__` in your config file and `TokenVariable1` release/environment variable in release definition, then the `__TokenVariable1__` will be replaced through **Tokenizer** task.

A related article: [Using Tokenization (Token Replacement) for Builds/Releases in vNext/TFS 2015](https://dustinoprea.com/2016/05/06/using-tokenization-token-replacement-for-buildsreleases-in-tfs-2015/)

Update:

You also can do it through PowerShell directly.

[Update configuration files using PowerShell](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sonam_rastogi_blogs/2014/08/18/update-configuration-files-using-powershell/)

Comment: right now I don't have any source code to change to tokenization concept but I have only the drop folder which contains dll's etc.

Comment: Do you mean there isn't the config file in drop folder? Where is it?

Comment: I have the config file in drop folder but I don't want to make any changes and I need to change in vsts release only

Comment: With Tokenizer task, you don't need to change the config file, just need to have a Configuration Json file. On the other hand, you also can do it through PowerShell directly (Check the update of my answer)

Comment: @sateesh What's the result now? Do you solve this issue?

Comment: Thanks, by seeing your "Update configuration files using PowerShell" my problem is solved

Comment: I faced the issue in config file. So, see my updated Question