# How to replace the web.config file content into Virtual Machine web.prod.config file

Tags: virtual-machine, configuration-files, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

am working on VSTS release task for deploying the Windows Services Project. Unfortunately, we are not creating any Build Definition for creating drop folder. But, my client will provide drop folder for this project, what I need is “I want to replace the web.config file content into VM web.prod.config file” at release level. For this, I referred the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution)

Answer (score 0):

Just refer to this thread to update file content: [How to override the keys in windows services .exe.config file through VSTS release definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556973/how-to-override-the-keys-in-windows-services-exe-config-file-through-vsts-relea/48574854).

If you need to copy files to other machine, you can use Windows Machine Copy file task.

Comment: thanks for your reply. As you said the Windows Machine Copy file task is used to copy the file, but what I required here is "I need to copy as well as change the name of the file"

Comment: @Mani You can rename the file through PowerShell task (Rename-Item) before copy task.